# Parse input string into vector of i16 in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm working through the exercises found at the bottom of [this page.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-03-hash-maps.html) The following code parses a space deliminated input string from the user into a `Vec<i16>`. If the input string is invalid, the code loops and prompts again. If the string is valid, it prints out the debug value of the `Vec<i16>` and prompts again.

The code works, but I feel there is a more idomatic Rust way to deal with this. Particularly, in the `get_input` function's looping and how its assigning the return value. Behold.

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    while let Some(ary) = get_input() {
        println!("{:?}", ary);
    }

    println!("Peace!");
}

fn get_input() -> Option<Vec<i16>> {
    let mut out: Option<Vec<i16>> = None;
    let mut valid = false;
    while !valid {
        // Get user input.
        print!("Enter series-> ");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

        // Parse it.
        match input.trim() {
            "q" => {
                valid = true;
                out = None;
            }
            _ => {
                let parsed = parse_input(input);
                if let Ok(_) = parsed {
                    out = Some(parsed.unwrap());
                    valid = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    out
}

fn parse_input(input: String) -> Result<Vec<i16>, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    input
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|token| token.parse::<i16>())
        .collect::<Result<Vec<i16>, _>>()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appreciate that you have formatted your code in the current idiomatic Rust style; thanks!

1. There's no reason to set the type of the `out` variable, type inference will handle it.
2. There's no need for the `out` or `valid` variables at all. Switch to an infinite `loop` and `return` from it when you need to.
3. It's likely overkill, but you are allocating and freeing the string for each loop. You could instead pull it outside of the loop to reuse it some, or pull the whole thing into a structure and reuse it for the entire program. You will need to ensure you clear the string before each use.
4. Don't `unwrap` inside of an `if let`. Instead, bind the result to a variable when doing the pattern matching and use it inside the block. (Clippy also tells you this, in a slightly different manner)
5. There's no benefit to taking a `String` in `parse_input`; you don't reuse the allocation. Accept a `&str` instead. (Clippy also tells you this)
6. You don't need any of the turbofish in `parse_input`; type inference knows what to do based on the return type.

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    while let Some(ary) = get_input() {
        println!("{:?}", ary);
    }

    println!("Peace!");
}

fn get_input() -> Option<Vec<i16>> {
    loop {
        // Get user input.
        print!("Enter series-> ");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

        // Parse it.
        match input.trim() {
            "q" => return None,
            input => {
                if let Ok(numbers) = parse_input(input) {
                    return Some(numbers);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn parse_input(input: &str) -> Result<Vec<i16>, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    input
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|token| token.parse())
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: That thing is called _turbofish_? I should learn more Rust.

Comment: Your list based response was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Rust too well, so take this review with a grain of salt. That being said, your `get_input` can be heavily simplified if you `return`. That way we don't need to remember whether the `parsed` input was valid: if it's valid we just `return`:

```
fn get_input() -> Option<Vec<i16>> {
    loop {
        // Get user input.
        print!("Enter series-> ");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut input = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

        // Parse it.
        match input.trim() {
            "q" => return None,
            _ => {
                let parsed = parse_input(input);
                if let Ok(out) = parsed {
                    return Some(out);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this prevents some errors that were possible before. For example you could have missed to set `out` and accidentally returned `None` instead of `Some`, e.g.

```
    // ...
    _ => {
        let parsed = parse_input(input);
        if let Ok(_) = parsed {
            valid = true;
            // whoops forgot out
        }
    }
```

This erroneous state cannot happen now.

Also note that we now have a simple `loop`. We don't have any `mut` bindings, only a single `if let` is left. Also note that we don't need to `unwrap` `parsed`: if `parsed` is an `Ok(out)`, we can use that `out`.

That being said, you should add an error message after the `match`, e.g.

```
match input.trim() {
    // same as above
}
println!("Your input could not get parsed. Please write space-separated numbers or 'q' to quit");
```